# Matching line subfield deliminated with square brackets

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a file that contains lines that contains fields delimited with square brackets, for example :

```
[tag "x"][severity "y"][id "z"][client 1]
```

I need to extract the data from the *client* field.  But I am struggling with the best way to do this.  Obviously its too advanced for the likes of *cut*.

I have been struggling to use *sed* (and I'm not even sure sed is the "best" or "most appropriate" tool), but sed regex like this doesn't seem to work :

```
sed 's/^.*\[client\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

I'm guessing the "most appropriate" tool is probably Perl with some sort of Perl module ?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Wow !  Thanks for seeking me out !  Sorry I deleted it, I was being hounded out with naysayers and downvoters, I tried to explain my reasoning, but that only seemed to make things worse.    But anyway, I appreaciate your generosity, so I'll go find where I undelete it and undelete it in your honour.  Thanks again.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, you can capture each bracket contents like so:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 while /(?<=\[)([^\]]+)(?=\])/g' file
tag "x"
severity "y"
id "z"
client 1
```

So then if you only want the `client` match you can do:

```
$ perl -lne 'for (/(?<=\[)([^\]]+)(?=\])/g) { print if /^client\b/ }' file
client 1
```

---

As pointed out in comments, `/\[([^\]]+)\]/g` is maybe a little more efficient.

```
$ perl -lne 'for (/\[([^\]]+)\]/g) { print if /^client\b/}' file
client 1
```

Comment: There's no need for the look-ahead and look-behind. `/\[([^\]]+)\]/g` will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show your expected output so it's a guess but based on what it looks like the script you posted is attempting to do - is this what you want?

```
$ sed 's/.*\[client *\([^]]*\).*/\1/g' file
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `tr -d`.

```
echo '[tag "x"][severity "y"][id "z"][client 1]' | tr -d '[]'
tag "x"severity "y"id "z"client 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '[tag "x"][severity "y"][id "z"][client 1]' | awk -F'[][]+' '{print $5}'

client 1
```